# Rails devise gem with rails-settings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a simple `User` model created with devise. I add additional attributes like `username`, `birthday`. Now I would like to add more user settings like `Boolean public`. But since I am aware that this attribute (i call them privacy settings) will not be the last created by me, I need a solution where I can expand the user settings easily without always updating the `User` modal. This is why I added `rails-settings` to my gem.

Now my question here first, is this best practise what I am doing here? And secondly, is there a good way to combine `rails-settings` with `devise` or is it better if I just use them seperatly. I am talking about the `registration/edit.html.erb` view, because there you can show all user fields but for my example not the rails-settings one.

Answer (score 0):

The User model, is basically a model that mustn't change too much during an app development, 3 or 4 times. It's easier and proper, i think,  to update your User model, than using rails-settings